# How to create a custom Gaussian activation function with Theano to use in a Keras layer

Tags: keras, theano

How would I write a Gaussian activation function using Theano for use in a Keras hidden layer.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the abstractions of keras and avoid the dependency to theano you need to use the [`backend` module from keras](https://keras.io/backend/).

Something like this:

```py
import keras.backend as K

def gaussian(x):
    return K.exp(-K.pow(x,2))
```

You can also look at [keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py) for inspiration.